# How to use WinScp to connect two windows 10 laptops

Tags: windows-10, ssh, winscp

I need to use WinScp to wirelessly connect two Dell laptops together and transfer files between them.
I have installed WinScp on both laptops.

Both laptops are connected to my wifi router.

but...
When I open and run WinScp on either laptop a or laptop B, I cannot get WinScp to discover  the other laptop, even if I enter the IP address, or the name of the laptop.

How can I get a connection working using WinScp ?

Both machines are running windows 10.

Comment: What is windowsScp? Do you mean WinSCP?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 nowadays contains both an SSH server and client
(`ssh.exe` residing in `C:\Windows\System32`).

You need an SSH server to use WinScp as client, but you may also use the
built-in Windows client.

While the Windows SSH client is installed by default,
the server is optional and needs to be enabled manually:

- Open Windows Settings
- Click Apps
- Click Optional features
- Click Add a feature
- Select OpenSSH Server
- Click Install.

Once added, it will be shown in the list of optional features, but you will still
need to start the service. This can be done in the Services applet, or in
PowerShell run as Administrator:

```
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
Start-Service sshd
```

To check that the port for the SSH server is open, enter:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *ssh*
```

Ensure that it says:

> Direction : Inbound
> Action : Allow

For more information see the article
[How To Use SSH Client and Server on Windows 10](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Use-SSH-Client-and-Server-on-Windows-10-1470/).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK You can't do this the way you propose. WinSCP is a client - you need an SSH server (scp runs on top of SSH) on one side to complement the SCP client.

OpenSSH is a server which can run under Windows and can fulfill this requirement. Have a look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse for how to enable it.